# CException::`RTTI Complete Object Locator in VC++ Application

Tags: visual-c++, crash, rtti

HI

I seem to be getting an CException::`RTTI Complete Object Locator exception once in a while in my VC++ application.

Does any of u know why this particular exception occurs.

i get this when calling the GetLocaleInfo() WINDOWS API.

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The call stack is corrupted. Higher version of Visual C++ injects "cookies" between variables on the stack to detect overwrites. You may want to upgrade to a new version of Visual C++ to have the compiler help you.

Otherwise it is very hard to catch the corruption. Use unit test to isolate bug. Increase the frequency of your data integrity validation.